# how to fix All final variables must be initialized, but 'city' isn't

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

this my code

```dart
final City city;
CityCard(city, {super.key, dynamic id, String? name, String? imageUrl});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
      child: Container(
        height: 150,
        width: 120,
        color: Color(0xffF6F7F8),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  city.imageUrl,
                  width: 120,
                  height: 102,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                city.isPopular
                    ? Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        child: Container(
                          width: 50,
                          height: 30,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: purpleColor,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(36),
                              )),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/star.png',
                              width: 22,
                              height: 22,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 11,
            ),
            Text(
              city.name,
              style: blackTextStyle.copyWith(
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i've tried to fix with but still can't

```
final City city;
CityCard(dynamic? city, {super.key, dynamic id, String? name, String? imageUrl});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you need to use `this.city`

```dart
CityCard( this.city,..);
```

Comment: it worked, thank you

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about  [dart](https://dart.dev/language)